# writing data from a file in a 2D array in c

Tags: c

Just a head start I'm still a noob in the whole programming thing, I have a basic level of it. 
SO I am writing this code to read data from a text file and display it on the black screen.

I started with this, but for some reason it is not working! can someone help me?

And another thing, if i wanted to write the city and the name of the candidate just like this photo how could i, since it is an array that accepts only integers?

1. City   Abdullah  Omar    Qusai   Basel
2. Alquds   187 52  166 297
3. Hebron   37  70  212 27
4. Ramallah 20  179 112 45
5. Bethlehem    244 121 308 19
6. Nablus   251 33  212 35

[image]

```
int main()
{
    int arr[4][5];
    int i,j;
    FILE *inp;
    inp = fopen("votes.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            fscanf(inp, "%d", &arr[i][j]);
        fclose (inp);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            printf("%d",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `votes.txt` verbatim, and also always check if `fopen()` returned a valid file stream.

Comment: you're also closing the file after the inner loop,, I doubt that is what you want. Move the `fclose` line outside of the first 2 `for` loops.

Comment: @MajdI, i suggest you to look at linked list before this task. -> http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html

Comment: @yano so if i moved the fclose outside the closing brace that will do it?

Comment: well that will fix one of your problems (also in the answer below). I don't know the input so I don't know if that will make everything work correctly. As you have it now, you are closing the file then still attempting to read from it.. I would expect that to be UB and probably crash.

Comment: @yano I'm still trying to figure out how to post the data here, since im new here. i posted them but they are a mess. but you could follow them up using the picture up obove

Comment: iharob, sadly. @Majdl this code is just achive simple task that you are trying to do -> https://ideone.com/HV4Fjc . With linked-list you dont have to make file operation every time you get input and also you dont have worry anymore about size, because it has dynamic size and also easy of insertion/deletion facility for you.

Answer (score 7):

If you indent the code properly you'll be able to see the problem more easily.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
   for (j=0; j<4; j++)
      fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]); // This ends the second for loop.

   // Then you are closing the file after one
   // run of the first loop.
   fclose (inp);
}
```

You need:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
   for (j=0; j<4; j++)
      fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]);
}

// Move it out of the loops.
fclose (inp);
```

To avoid problems like this, it will be better to always use `{}` to scope the loops, even for one liners.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++){
   for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
      fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]);
   }
}
```

**Other problems**

1. You need to add code to skip the first line. It does not have data in the same format.

   Add a function

   ```
   void skipLine(FILE* in)
   {
      int c;
      while ( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF && c != '\n');
   }
   ```

   and use it before you read the data.

   ```
   skipLine(inp);
   ```
2. You need to add code to read the name from each row.

   Add a variable for `name`

   ```
   char name[200]; // Make it large enough
   ```

   and make sure to read it for every line.

   ```
   for (i=0; i<5; i++)
   {
      // Make sure to limit the number of characters being read.
      fscanf(inp, "%199s", name);
      for (j=0; j<4; j++)
      {
         fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]);
      }
   }
   ```
3. Use of the indices `i` and `j` are not right. You have

   ```
   int a[4][5];
   ```

The range of valid values for `i` needs to be `0-3` while that for `j` needs to be `0-4`. Given that there are 5 rows of data what you need is:

```
    int a[5][4];
```

**Check the return values of `fscanf`**

As a matter of good practice, always check the return values of `fscanf`. This will allow you to catch errors and help you with troubleshooting problems of reading from disk.

Change the code that reads the data to:

```
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
       if ( fscanf(inp, "%199s", name) != 1 )
       {
          fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read the name\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       for (j=0; j<4; j++)
       {
          if ( fscanf(inp,"%d",&arr[i][j]) != 1 )
          {
             fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read the number from %d-th row and %d-th column\n", i, j);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Skipping braces when you use this style is not nice anyway, that could be another source of confusion.'

Comment: Your indices are still wrong. . should be `i<4` and `j<5`

Comment: @yano No, actually observing data ,declaration should be changed to `int arr[5][4]` not the loop conditions .

Comment: @ameyCU Oh, based on the linked-image? Sure, I didn't look at that before commenting,, whoops. Then I think this answer should include a `int arr[5][4];` declaration since that deviates from the OP code.

Comment: @yano the crashing stopped, but still not working!

Comment: @MajdI Just using this loop won't as I think . Maybe you can read  the complete line with something as this - `fscanf(inp,"%*s %d %d %d %d",&v1,&v2,&v3,&v4);` . Ignore first string and then store 4 integers in variables. _But ofcourse after reading first line of data_.

Comment: @ameyCU but storing it in variables won't help me, i need to store them in an array!

Comment: @MajdI Yes, it is just an example , you can store in arrays accordingly .

Comment: @MajdI Yeah if your text file contains data other than just the integers you'll have to ignore that in some fashion. Anything along the lines of what this answer or ameyCU suggested should be just fine. If you're still having trouble, start small (just trying reading a string and/or int per line). Stepping through with a debugger would help too.

Comment: alright imma try it out now and see how it goes, thanks guys :)